# Radiative transfer through two coaxial apertures (ray optics)

Tags: radiation, geometric-optics

I'm struggling to find an expression that describes the radiative transfer from a planar Lambertian source (extended, at $x_s=0$) through two coaxial apertures ($r_a1, r_a2, x_a1,x_a2$) onto a finite, circular detector ($r_d, x_d$).

All in the limit of geometrical optics.

Any link, chapter or explanation would help.
[image]

Edit: added a sketch.

Source and detector in grey, source on the left hand side, det on the rhs. then, two apertures in black. (all circular and arbitrarily thin). distances and radii as in the text. and, all coaxial (excuse the crappy drawing)

I am looking for an analytic expression , probably multi-equations depending on size/distance ratios.

I understand that monte carlo would ve straight forward, but still hope there is an equation...

Comment: I’m a bit unsure about the geometry. Could you add a diagram?

Comment: i cannot draw right now, but, imagine a right handed xyz system. then, there is a lambertian disc in the zy plane, centered at the origin of radius r_source. parallel to the source, but shifted by x_ap,1 and x_ap,2 are two apertures of radii r_ap,1 and r_ap,2. then, finally again paralle (in zy-plane)l and centered on y=0, z=0 a detector of radius r_det. how much light does reach the detector if the source has (lambertian) radiance L? hope it's clearer now..

Comment: I’ll wait until you have time

Comment: I added a sketch, I hope its clearer now?

Comment: Very helpful! What quality to you wish to find? The specific intensity reaching the specific intensity reaching the detector? Is the first aperture always larger than the first? I think you can do this just with etendue.

Comment: i want to find the total power irradiating the detector, given the geometry & assuming the soure is lambertian with radiance L. In a first pass, lets assume the fisrt aperture is bigger than the second aperture and the detector has equal size as the second aperture. i couldt do it with etendue so far, i dont know what defines the effective source diameter and position as the second aperture cuts some of the light from the first aperture.